# SonarQube: How to deactivate rules in a default Quality Profile?

Tags: sonarqube

I have the default profile for Java in SonarQube called Sonar way.
[image: Default QualityProfile]

When I try to deactivate any rules in it, there is no way I can do it.

[image: Default Rules]

How do I specifically disable rules for this profile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not. Starting with SonarQube 6.5 default profiles are not editable. Instead, make a new profile and [copy the Sonar way rules into it](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles#QualityProfiles-Copytherulesfromoneprofiletoanother?). Then you'll be able to edit your copy.

If after each upgrade you want to make sure you haven't missed any exiting new rules, just [compare your copy with Sonar way](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles#QualityProfiles-Comparetwoprofiles?) and edit your profile to handle the differences.